# Is there a way to get proper json out of this api?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from the following api http://www.tandemsoftware.es/webservice/test_cruz.php?param=1 . If I browse to it I get an array decorated with `<pre></pre>` tag which is not a json. I want to get this data with an ajax call instead of php code. Is this possible? I wrote a script which when I run it fails with 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' and it breaks before I get to success function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        headers: {          
            Accept: " application/json; charset=utf-8",         
            "Content-Type": " application/json; charset=utf-8"   
        },
        url: "http://www.tandemsoftware.es/webservice/test_cruz.php?param=1",       
        dataType: "jsonp",                
        success: function(response){     
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        }

    });    
});
</script>
```

Is there a any way I can get the data right?

Comment: remove `<pre>` tag from ur php page.. after that u will be able to continue;

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp",` - it isn't jsonp, it's not even json .. it's PHP var_dump, which you'll have to parse yourself

Comment: if `www.tandemsoftware.es` is not same origin, you wont get far anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your url returns

```
<pre>array(54) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["IdMarcaVeh"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["MarcaVeh"]=>
    string(10) "Alfa Romeo"
  }
  [1]=>
```

Which is not json, its a `var_dump` on some array. Additonally there is html at start (`<pre>`). Which is also not valid json.

You should convert your array to a json string and return/echo that

```
$data = ['some', 'string'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Also you should use `dataType: 'json'` as you probably dont the `jsonp`

Comment: I am pretty familiar with what is a json string. Can I somehow convert what I get to a json string without breaking the code. That is my question.

Comment: If I wrote the api myself I wouldn't ask in the first place. I can't affect how they return data. So I am asking:
- Is there a way to capture this data in the format that they are sending and somehow convert it to json via ajax and js? Since I am not familiar with php, I wonder if there is a way to convert it with js. Just that.

Comment: @Silisav hmm I guess that would be not that easy to write a parser for converting a php vardump to json. Also I wouldn't call that an api, its basically just debug output.

Comment: it's cross origin request, and there's no cors headers, so doomed to failure regardless

Comment: Well it is terrible implemented anyway. I will see if they can change their functions to something that makes sense. Its cross domain call btw, it needs jsonp, otherwise you get the "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: @Silisav but then it needs to return jsonp

Comment: indeed, in needs JSONP to be understood and sent appropriately by the server ... you can't just tell anything to "send JSONP" and expect it to work

Comment: JSONP request creates a `<script src="url">` tag ... and the server better send the `json` with the "agreed" callback - or it will fail

Comment: In any case it is pretty messed up. I will contact them to see if they can provide something that makes sense. Thanks for your time!